# RecyclerView da un URL en posición incorrecta en SearchView al hacer Click

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, android-recyclerview, searchview

:D
He estado luchando por obtener la posición correcta de una URL en un RecyclerView. Utilizo el FCM para obtener datos y almacenarlos en SharedPreference. Implementé un SearchView en mi RecyclerView para filtrar una palabra específica, funciona bien.

El problema es que cuando buscas esa palabra y luego haces clic en recyclerView, te envía a la url en la primera posición del recyclerView original, no la filtrada. Traté de cambiar la posición en mi BindViewHolder, pero no parece funcionar. También para cambiar la posición también en mi función onClick dentro de mi ViewHolder pero no funciona, puede ser porque la función onClick requiere un Int y encuentra lo que tengo en Notificaciones. Este es el error que me da. [image: Este es el error que me da]

y cuando lo cambio a Notificaciones en mi interfaz, onClick deja de funcionar.

**Este es mi Adapter**

```
class NotifAdapter(private var mContext: Context, items:ArrayList<Notificaciones>, var listener: onClickListenerForAdapter): RecyclerView.Adapter<NotifAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var items: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null
var itemsFiltered: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null

init {
    this.items = items
    this.itemsFiltered = items
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotifAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val vista = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cv_notif, parent, false)
    val viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista,listener)

    return viewHolder
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemsFiltered?.count()!!
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotifAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = itemsFiltered?.get(position)
    holder.title?.text = item?.title
    holder.body?.text = item?.body
    holder.fecha?.text = item?.fecha
    holder.img?.setImageResource(item?.img!!)
    
    //Animaciones para la imagen
    holder.img?.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.aparecer_animacion)

    //Animación para el mensaje
    holder.mensaje?.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.crecer_animacion)
}

inner class ViewHolder(vista:View, listener:onClickListenerForAdapter): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista), View.OnClickListener{
    var vista  = vista
    var title: TextView? = null
    var body: TextView? = null
    var fecha: TextView? = null
    var listener:onClickListenerForAdapter? = null
    var img: ImageView? = null
    var mensaje:RelativeLayout? = null
     var items: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null
     var itemsFiltered: ArrayList<Notificaciones>?= null
    
    init {
        title = vista.findViewById(R.id.tituloNotif)
        body = vista.findViewById(R.id.textNotif)
        fecha = vista.findViewById(R.id.fechaNotif)
        img = vista.findViewById(R.id.imgNotif)
        mensaje = vista.findViewById(R.id.contenido)
        this.listener = listener
        vista.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        
        this.listener?.onClick(v!!, adapterPosition)
    }
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val Key = constraint.toString()
            itemsFiltered = if (Key.isEmpty()) {
                items
            } else {
                val lstFiltered = java.util.ArrayList<Notificaciones>()
                for (row in items!!) {
                    if (row.title.toLowerCase().contains(Key.toLowerCase()) || row.body.toLowerCase().contains(Key.toLowerCase())) {
                        lstFiltered.add(row)
                    }
                }
                lstFiltered
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = itemsFiltered
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
            itemsFiltered = results.values as java.util.ArrayList<Notificaciones>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}}
```

**Este es mi Modelo**

```
class Notificaciones(title: String, body: String, fecha: String, imagen: Int){

var title = ""
var body = ""
var fecha = ""
var img = 0
init {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.fecha = fecha
    this.img = imagen
}}
```

**Es es la clase de mi activity**

```
class ventanaNotif : AppCompatActivity() {


val notifList = ArrayList<Notificaciones>()
var lista:RecyclerView? = null
lateinit var adaptador: NotifAdapter
var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
lateinit var shared: SharedPreferences
private val COUNT_KEY = "Conteo"
var busqueda: EditText?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventana_notif)

    //findViews
    lista = findViewById(R.id.rv_notif) //RecyclerView nuevo
    busqueda = findViewById(R.id.busqueda)//Busqueda de texto

    //Nuevo RecyclerView
    lista?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    lista?.layoutManager = layoutManager

    adaptador = NotifAdapter(this ,notifList, object: onClickListenerForAdapter {

            override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {

                /*Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Esta es mi notificacion" +
                        "${notifList.get((notificaciones.fecha.toInt())}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()*/

                val url = notifList.get(index).fecha.toString()
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                startActivity(i)
        }

    })
    lista?.adapter = adaptador
    
    //funciones
    notifData()
    
    butBorrar.setOnClickListener {
        shared.edit().clear().apply()
        adaptador.notifyItemRemoved(adaptador.itemCount)
    }

    //Metodo de busqueda por TextWatcher
    busqueda?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            adaptador.filter.filter(s)
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    })

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ventanaHome::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
    super.onBackPressed()
}

fun notifData() {

    shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY, 0)

    for ((x, valor) in (1..count).withIndex()) {


        notifList.add(
            Notificaciones(
                "${shared.getString("TituloData${valor}", "Todo bien")}",
                "${shared.getString("CuerpoData${valor}", "No hay más notificaciones")}",
                "${shared.getString("UrlData${valor}", "Sin URL ")}", R.drawable.ic_steren2)
        )

     
        adaptador.notifyItemInserted(adaptador.itemCount)

    }

}}
```

**Esta es la interfaz que uso para el onClick del RecyclerView**

```
interface onClickListenerForAdapter {
fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int)}
```

Ya intenté cambiarla a notificaciones: Notificaciones para que se ajuste al onClick de mi Adapter

```
 interface onClickListenerForAdapter {
fun onClick(vista: View, notificaciones:Notificaciones)}
```

pero al cambiarla el onClick en mi activity ya abre la url, porque ya no tiene un index.

```
adaptador = NotifAdapter(this ,notifList, object: onClickListenerForAdapter {

            override fun onClick(vista: View, index: Int) {

                val url = notifList.get(index).fecha.toString()
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                startActivity(i)
        }

    })
```

Es el segundo día, y aún no puedo resolver este error. Agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar :)